# SQL server integer vs decimal SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, integer, decimal, sqsh

This is probably a newb question but...I was working on a db in SQSH and it had integer type values that were large (a population attribute). When I wanted to sum these up I got an arithmetic overflow exception. Then I cast the values to Decimal and everything worked OK (no overflow). However, everywhere I read says that Integer and Decimal are the same thing. So why is this happening ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: INT and DECIMAL are not the same by any means.  I'm not sure what you've been reading.  Try starting here...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An integer type is a 4 byte number that can go as high as 2,147,483,647.   A decimal can go substantially higher.   Both are stored as integers, but the decimal allows for a value to represent digits past the decimal sign.   You could also use BIGINT (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) in place of integer.

Answer (score 3):

You have have a `decimal` datatype with the precision and scale that is greater than the max limit of the `int` datatype.  For instance, `decimal(18, 0)` will have a larger capacity than `int` (which tops out at `2147483647`).

Granted, `int` only takes up 4 bytes and you can't get away with more space consumption with something like `decimal(18, 0)`.  But it will get you aruond the max limit of `int`.

Answer (score 2):

From Books OnLine

[decimal and numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

> decimal[ (p[ , s] )] and numeric[ (p[ , s] )]  Fixed precision and
> scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from -
> 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1.

[int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)

> Has a length of 4 bytes, and stores numbers from -2,147,483,648
> through 2,147,483,647.

So, Decimal can store much greater value than Int.